# center text in a view on top of the screen (react-native)

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a view with height of 200 and with some background color. on top of the view i want to place two texts  in the center of the screen right below the toolbar.  my code is not centering the texts. texts are appearing on the left side but i want them to be centered. 
I am using Base.js style script as a way to standardize my application to reuse styles

see attached image

[image]

see code below

```
//Base.js
import {StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native'

export const dimensions = {
  fullHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  fullWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width
}

export const colors  = {
  primary: '#039BE5',
  secondary: '#027CB7',
  tertiary: '#FF4081'
}

export const padding = {
  sm: 10,
  md: 20,
  lg: 30,
  xl: 40
}

export const margin = {
    margin_1dp: 1,
    margin_4dp: 4,
  }

export const fonts = {
  font_18sp: 18,
  font_44sp: 44,
  lg: 28,
  //primary: 'Cochin'
}

export const pos = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0, 
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent:'center',
}

// added below our colors, fonts, padding etc
// base styles
const baseStyles = {
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      alignItems: 'stretch',
    },
    header: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      position: pos.position,
      top: 0,
      fontSize: fonts.font_44sp,
      fontFamily: fonts.primary,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'black',
      textAlign: 'center',
    },
    sub_header: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      position: pos.position,
      top: 55,
      fontSize: fonts.font_18sp,
      fontFamily: fonts.primary,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'white',
      textAlign: 'center',
    },
    image: {


      height: 200, justifyContent:'center', backgroundColor: '#00BCD4'

    },
    section: {
      paddingVertical: padding.lg,
      paddingHorizontal: padding.xl
    },
  }

  export default function createStyles(overrides = {}) {
    return StyleSheet.create({...baseStyles, ...overrides})
  }
```

```
//This is an example code for NavigationDrawer//
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import react in our code.
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
// import all basic components
import createStyles from '../styles/Base.js'
const styles = createStyles()

//import styles from './Style.js'

export default class Screen1 extends Component {
  //Screen1 Component
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
           <View style={{  height: 200, justifyContent:'center', backgroundColor: '#00BCD4' }}  />

          <Text style={styles.header}> $0.00 </Text>
          <Text style={styles.sub_header}> Current Balance </Text>
        </View>


    );
  }
```

texts should be center in the middle of the screen and below the toolbar.
can anyone help fix my code so that the texts are center? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `flexDirection` in react-native is **column** ... so you don need to specify it ... and `alignItems` will center children **horizontally** with column-flex-direction

```
 <View
    style={{ alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#00BCD4', height: 200 }}
  >
    <Text style={styles.header}> $0.00 </Text>
    <Text style={styles.sub_header}> Current Balance </Text>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this might not solve everything but a common mistake people make when it comes to flexbox is they don't realize when they specify a `flex-direction`, the styles you use to center get reversed.

Typically if `flex-direction` was set to default which is `row`, you would use `align-items` to vertically center.

However, because you have it set to `column`, you need to use `justify-content` instead.

This is a pretty good article on flex. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: the default `flexDirection` in react-native is **column** not row